# Does Abjurant Champion Benefit Urgent Shield?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, class-feature

> **Abjurant Armor (Su):** Any time you cast an abjuration spell that grants you an armor bonus or shield bonus to AC, you can increase the value of the bonus by your abjurant champion class level. Abjurant champions rely on *shield* and similar spells instead of actual armor.

> **Immediate Magic:** You gain a spell-like ability that reflects your chosen school of magic.
>
> [...]
>
> *Urgent Shield (Abjuration):* You create a temporary Shield of force that grants you a +2 Shield Bonus to AC

Now because this is a spell like ability and not a spell, it could be argued either way. Can anyone clarify on this?

Answer (score 4):

Correct; though spell-like abilities are *like* spells in certain ways, they are *not* spells, and really in a lot of ways are very different from spells. The abjurant armor feature only applies to spells.

That said, you might ask your DM if you can have this one; *urgent shield* isn’t all that good and this bonus is not that big a deal. Wizards are so powerful that he may not want to give you anything more, though.

As a side-note, the best spells for an abjurant champion’s features are *luminous armor* and its *greater* counterpart from *Book of Exalted Deeds*.